# Got an error reading communication packets in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, connection, google-cloud-sql, database-connectivity

From 31th March I've got following error in Google Cloud SQL:

> Got an error reading communication packets.

I have been using Google Cloud SQL for 2 years, but never faced with such problem.
I'm very worried about it.

This is detail error message:

```
textPayload:  "2019-04-29T17:21:26.007574Z 203385 [Note] Aborted connection 203385 to db: {db_name} user: {db_username} host: 'cloudsqlproxy~{private ip}' (Got an error reading communication packets)"
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details about your issue? Complete error messages and what kind of operations do you perform, with code samples if possible.

Comment: I am having the same error right now while my application has been running for over a year without problems. Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: Hi Hui, Can you have a look at my answer below and check if the answer resolves your issue? This question is getting a lot of views, its important we find a good answer to your issue/question. Kindly revert back.

Answer (score 5):

While it is true that this error message often occurs after a maintenance period, it isn't necessarily a cause for concern as this is a known behavior by MySQL.

Possible explanations about why this issue is happening are :

1. The large increase of connection requests to the instance, with the
   number of active connections increasing over a short period of time.
   The freezing / unavailability of the instance can also occur due to
   the burst of connections happening in a very short time interval. It
   is observed that this freezing always happens with an increase of
   connection requests. This increase in connections causes the
   instance to be overloaded and hence unavailable to respond to
   further connection requests until the number of connections
   decreases or the instance stabilizes.
2. The server was too busy to accept new connections.
3. There were high rates of previous connections that were not closed
   correctly.
4. The client terminated it abnormally.
5. `readTimeout` setting being set too low in the MySQL driver.
6. In an excerpt from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections#timeout), it is stated that:

> There are many reasons why a connection attempt might not succeed.
> Network communication is never guaranteed, and the database might be
> temporarily unable to respond. Make sure your application handles
> broken or unsuccessful connections gracefully.

7. Also a low Cloud SQL Proxy version can be the reason for such
   incident issues. Possible upgrade to the latest version of (v1.23.0)
   can be a troubleshooting solution.
8. IP from where you are trying to connect, may not be added to the
   Authorized Networks in the Cloud SQL instance.

Some possible workaround for this issue, depending which is your case could be one of the following:

1. In the case that the issue is related to a high load, you could
   retry the connection, using an [exponential backoff](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections#backoff) to prevent
   from sending too many simultaneous connection requests. The best
   practice here is to exponentially back off your connection requests
   and add [randomized backoffs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/troubleshooting?hl=en#connectivity)to avoid throttling, and potentially
   overloading the instance. As a way to mitigate this issue in the
   future, it is recommended that connection requests should be
   spaced-out to prevent overloading. Although, depending on how you
   are connecting to Cloud SQL, exponential backoffs may already be in
   use by default with certain ORM packages.
2. If the issue could be related to an [accumulation of long-running
   inactive connections](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections#kill), you would be able to know if it is your case
   using [`show full processlist`](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/troubleshooting#managing-instances)on your database looking for
   the connections with high `Time` or connections where `Command` is
   `Sleep`.

   If this is your case you would have a few possible options:

   If you are not using a connection pool you could try to update the client application logic to properly close connections immediately at the end of an operation or use a connection pool to limit your connections lifetime. In particular, it is ideal to manage the connection count by using a [connection pool](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections#count). This way unused connections are recycled and also the number of simultaneous connection requests can be limited through the use of the `maximum pool size` parameter.

   If you are using a connecting pool, you could return the idle connections to the pool immediately at the end of an operation and set a shorter timeout by adjusting `wait_timeout` or `interactive_timeout`[flag values](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags). Set CloudSQL wait_timeout [flag](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#list-flags-mysql) to 600 seconds to force refreshing connections.
3. To check the network and port connectivity once -

> Step 1. Confirm TCP connectivity on port 3306 with tcptraceroute or
> netcat.
>
> Step 2. If [Step 1] succeeded then try to check if there are any
> errors in using mysql client to check timeout/error.

4. When the client might be terminating the connection abruptly you
   could check for:

   If the MySQL client or mysqld server are receiving a packet bigger
   than `max_allowed_packet` bytes, or the client receiving a packet
   too large message,if it so you could send smaller packets or
   increase the [`max_allowed_packet`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) flag value on both client
   and server. If there are transactions that are not being properly
   committed using both "begin" and "commit", there is the need to
   update the client application logic to properly commit the
   transaction.
5. There are [several utilities](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/debugging-connectivity#tools_for_debugging_connectivity) that I think will be helpful here,
   if you can install [`mtr`](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/debugging-connectivity#mtr) and the [`tcpdump`](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/debugging-connectivity#tcpdump) utilities to
   monitor the packets during these connection-increasing events.
6. It is strongly recommended to enable the general_log in the
   database flags. Another suggestion is to also enable the slow_query
   database flag and output to a file. Also have a look at this
   [GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/126#issuecomment-338303438) and go through the list of additional
   solutions proposed for this issue [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/communication-errors.html)

Answer (score -1):

This error message indicates a connection issue, either because your application doesn't terminate connections properly or because of a network issue.

As suggested in these troubleshooting steps for [MySQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues) or [PostgreSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/diagnose-issues) instances from the GCP docs, you can start debugging by checking that you follow [best practices for managing database connections](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections#opening_and_closing_connections).